# Audio out (What I Hear) to an UPnP device

Tags: windows, audio, upnp

I don't understand why this hasn't been addressed before, can't seem to find much info on this on the interwebs.

I am sometimes listening to something on my computer and I want to play it to my XBOX 360 or Sonos (Multi-Room Music Manager) and I can't do that in a simple one-click way.  I would want to simply be able to select the UPnP devices around me as my audio output and be able to play anything that my computer would play otherwise.

Do you guys know of any software that enables this?  Have you heard of this idea before?

Comment: "have you ever head of this?" Nope. Also, probably get a better response over at Super USer.

Answer (score 0):

Remotely telling your media-server (PC, NAS etc.) to push audio or video to a networked device (tv, stereo etc.) with DLNA. This is the closest thing I can think of.

http://www.dlna.org/digital_living/possibilities/

http://www.dlna.org/digital_living/getting_started/